# Disappearing call logs later automatically it can be viewed....!

Tags: call-history

Am using Samsung note 3 neo from few day I am facing a problem in call logs whenever this is a missed call, dialed call or rejected call that will not show in call log for certain period later it will listed and show.. I have cleared all the cached files then also issue is presuming same. Please help !!

Comment: Need more details. What android version? When did it start happening (did it start happening after you did something specific)? Are you on stock rom?

Comment: Andriod Version : 4.4.2
Started from last 10-15 days back nothing specific i did 
No idea about stock rom

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, then apps, scroll to show all apps, go down until you see a phone icon that says call and message log, force stop it and switch phone off, leave about 2 minutes and restart phone, should all be back in place, hope it helps